# How to detect blinks using openCV in iphone

Tags: iphone, opencv

I want to make an app on blink detection .

I am able to detect eyes but I am not able to detect blinks .

Have anyone worked on this? the major issue is to find blink. do anyone know how to do this ?

P.S.> I am using openCV to detect eyes

Answer (score 2):

You might find this [paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.73.3862&rep=rep1&type=pdf) to be helpful. Also [Google Scholar](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=blink%20detection&btnG=Search&as_sdt=0,1&as_ylo=&as_vis=0) is definitely your friend in computer vision :)

Eye blinks take between 200-400ms in humans. So, you would expect @ 15 fps to get between 3-6 frames of a blink. So, I would think since you already know the eye-location, you could use a combination of a ROI masking and skin detection with a threshold to detect a blink after two-consecutive frames above a threshold.

Also, possibly simple frame differencing with a state-machine may be able to reliably detect blinks fairly well once you isolate the eye from the rest of the face.

Comment: Have you implemented blink detection? If so can you please provide me some sample code? Thanks

Comment: "Also, possibly simple frame differencing with a state-machine may be able to reliably detect blinks fairly well once you isolate the eye from the rest of the face."

can you explain that elaborately sir?